# User Interface Not Reflecting Changes i make

Tags: vb.net, winforms

[image: In the designer...]

[image: While Running...]

Basically the question is, Why are **NONE** of the changes I've been making in the designer reflecting on the program when it runs ?

'none' is in bold because I've tried moving everything around and nothing seems to be affecting it, it's like it's reading from a different design file, I tried reloading the project and that did nothing, and none of my code affects position of any items on the form (way too much to post it all)

Comment: Did you rebuild the project?  Did you get any errors?

Comment: I've rebuilt it, and reloaded it D:

Comment: oh, and there is no error's or exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an option in Tools menu->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run: "On Run, when build or deployment errors occur:"->Launch old version. Do you have it set to that?

Comment: How about deleting the contents of the project's bin directory and inspecting it to make sure the build is going there, and then running it directly from that directory?